# Slow boot time in my Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot

My PC was booting very fast because I have SSD however after I enabled and disabled bitlocker now my PC boot time is 1 minute and 10 sec !! I tried to use windows performance recorder to see what is wrong but once started the recorder I could not login into windows because of blue screen !! so i disabled the recorder.

Any advise how I find the problem that made my boot time slow ?

Here is the event pic
[image]

Here are the data

```
 EventData 

  BootTsVersion 2 
  BootStartTime 2019-02-01T20:23:29.029447200Z 
  BootEndTime 2019-02-01T20:25:18.984717500Z 
  SystemBootInstance 453 
  UserBootInstance 451 
  BootTime 82979 
  MainPathBootTime 13279 
  BootKernelInitTime 39 
  BootDriverInitTime 441 
  BootDevicesInitTime 4344 
  BootPrefetchInitTime 0 
  BootPrefetchBytes 0 
  BootAutoChkTime 0 
  BootSmssInitTime 3448 
  BootCriticalServicesInitTime 121 
  BootUserProfileProcessingTime 463 
  BootMachineProfileProcessingTime 53 
  BootExplorerInitTime 3552 
  BootNumStartupApps 4 
  BootPostBootTime 69700 
  BootIsRebootAfterInstall false 
  BootRootCauseStepImprovementBits 0 
  BootRootCauseGradualImprovementBits 0 
  BootRootCauseStepDegradationBits 0 
  BootRootCauseGradualDegradationBits 0 
  BootIsDegradation false 
  BootIsStepDegradation false 
  BootIsGradualDegradation false 
  BootImprovementDelta 0 
  BootDegradationDelta 0 
  BootIsRootCauseIdentified false 
  OSLoaderDuration 904 
  BootPNPInitStartTimeMS 39 
  BootPNPInitDuration 5099 
  OtherKernelInitDuration 111 
  SystemPNPInitStartTimeMS 5193 
  SystemPNPInitDuration 397 
  SessionInitStartTimeMS 5608 
  Session0InitDuration 1441 
  Session1InitDuration 407 
  SessionInitOtherDuration 1599 
  WinLogonStartTimeMS 9056 
  OtherLogonInitActivityDuration 153 
  UserLogonWaitDuration 9638
```

I already tried windows performance kit and because of the recorder I could not even login into windows because of blue screen. In addition I posted the time of each process and it appear BootPostBootTime is the problem but I dont know what it is and how to solve it.

**Update**
Here is a picture from process monitor display the most taken time at startup but I dont know how to fix this as I afraid to stop a process that will take down windows so please advise

**As for Bitlocker all drives are unencrypted and the service is not running**

[image]

Comment: Go to Task Manager and try looking in the Start-Up tab for things that have a high "start up impact"? Maybe disable all but essential stuff in msconfig or on that page in task manager and see if it helps then enable one by one?

Comment: When you say disabled. Do you mean suspended? Or actually decrypted the drive? "manage-bde -status" may help you confirm, or it could even be showing a decryption in progress

Comment: @harrymc the answer in the other post does not resolve my problem it only say how to trace it and I already did now how to resolve ??!!

Comment: @harrymc I added more details please reopen .... thanks

Comment: @Welliam Your question will only be reopened when it’s clear it isn’t a duplicate and you have provided enough information to answer your question.  It’s not clear if you have BitLocker enabled or disabled at this point.  You were asked if you suspended BitLocker or Disabled it.  If you suspended BitLocker protection that something entirely different to disabling BitLocker protection

Comment: You have supplied lots of helpful information, but you need to respond positively, when we ask for specific information.  If you get frustrated and continue to respond in a way that shows that frustration, you won’t end up providing the clarification actually required to answer your question

Comment: There are many posts on the subject on our site, Microsoft's site and in general on the Internet. You are not using a good method of analysis and have not benefited from the link I gave you on our site, just arrogantly saying that you know it all. You also downvote people who try to help, which doesn't encourage them to continue helping. This isn't recommended behavior - we expect posters to be nice and to listen to and to study our suggestions. Solving problems here is a cooperative effort, and you are not cooperating.

Comment: @harrymc I am not arrogant but the info you posted I read them all before because I am surfing the net for a week now for this problem however sorry